# Problems with jQuery animate and z-index/Relative Positioning

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, z-index, css-position

I'm trying to get a div to encompass the other divs on mouseover using position: relative. Unfortunately it only works for the last div. If you mouseover the others, they only cover the divs that are declared before them.

The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/YuKaR/3/

Absolute positioning works fine, but unfortunately I cannot use absolute positioning for this particular app.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I strongly suggest you use a stylesheet on your fiddle.  It's nearly impossible to read it inline.

Comment: Sorry, not sure how I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with relative positioning is that positions are relative to their normal position, meaning if you resize an element in the middle, the browser will move and re-flow everything that comes after it.

A few changes needed to be made to make it work. If you want to use relative positioning, you have to wrap your resizing divs in fixed size containers, so when they're resizing they won't break the element flow. Your divs have 150px width and height, the fixed sized container must be big enough to hold it, assuming the default box-model it's 150px + 10px*2 padding + 1px*2 border = 172px. As the element flow is controled by the containers, I moved margin to the container in the css.

By wrapping them in an additional fixed sized div, element flow will never change, your resizing divs will just bleed through the edges of the container, overlapping the other containers (overflow:visible).

I also changed your z-index logic, as you need to set the z-index for the containers now (which will apply to all child elements). By default everything has z-index of 2. When the div is resized back to its original state, I set its container's z-index back to 2 after the animation, using a callback function on .animate(). When resizing starts, all containers are reset to z-index 2 in case there is one still animating back to its original state, the currently resizing div's container is set to z-index 3 to make it appear on top of all the others.

http://jsfiddle.net/x34d3/

HTML markup:

```
 <div id="main" style="position:relative;z-index:1;">

     <div class="container"><div id="lefttop" class="resizer">left top</div></div>
     <div class="container"><div id="righttop" class="resizer">right top</div></div>
     <p style="clear:both;"></p>
     <div class="container"><div id="leftbottom" class="resizer">left bottom</div></div>
     <div class="container"><div id="rightbottom" class="resizer">right bottom</div></div>

 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.resizer { position:relative; border: 1px solid #000000; padding:10px; margin:0px; width:150px; height:150px; }

.container { position:relative; padding:0px; margin:8px; float:left; z-index: 2; width:172px; height:172px; }
```

javascript:

```
$(function(){
     $(".resizer").mouseover(function() {
         $(".container").css('z-index' , '2');
         $(this).parent().css('z-index' , '3');
         if(this.id == "lefttop"){
             aoptions = {width: "340px", height: "340px", backgroundColor: "#CCCCCC", left: '0', top: '0'}
         }else if(this.id == "righttop"){
             aoptions = {width: "340px", height: "340px", backgroundColor: "#CCCCCC", left: '-=190', top: '0'}
         }else if(this.id == "leftbottom"){
             aoptions = {width: "340px", height: "340px", backgroundColor: "#CCCCCC", left: '0', top: '-=190'}
         }else if(this.id == "rightbottom"){
             aoptions = {width: "340px", height: "340px", backgroundColor: "#CCCCCC", left: '-=190', top: '-=190'}
         }
         $(this).css('z-index' , '99').animate(aoptions, 800);
     }).mouseout(function(){
         if(this.id == "lefttop"){
             aoptions = {width: "150px",    height: "150px", backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF", left: '0', top: '0'}
         }else if(this.id == "righttop"){
             aoptions = {width: "150px",    height: "150px", backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF", left: '+=190'}
         }else if(this.id == "leftbottom"){
             aoptions = {width: "150px",    height: "150px", backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF", left: '0', top: '+=190'}
         }else if(this.id == "rightbottom"){
             aoptions = {width: "150px",    height: "150px", backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF", left: '+=190', top: '+=190'}
         }
         $(this).animate(aoptions, 800, function(){
             $(this).parent().css('z-index' , '2');
         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: Looks an awful lot like my solution that was posted first, just not as nice =D

Comment: @DarthJDG - My OCD doesn't let me overlook places where I can optimize code or make it look more organized. That's why I deviated.

Comment: @DarthJDG - I want to make it clear, I wasn't trying to be rude. Reading it back, it kind of looks that way. I meant nice in terms of formatting/organization, which I know you were just getting the original to work and keep everything the same.  No hard feelings!

Comment: @Scott: No worries, I didn't take it the wrong way, a bit of pun in my post was intended too. It takes a lot more to offend me in any way. :) I was just typing the end of my post when yours popped up, I just typed too much not to post it. You solution looks and works a lot nicer.

Answer (score 4):

Took me a while, but I finally figured it out.  Take a look at this ***[working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMaverick/HSR9s/)***:

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="main">

     <div class="overlay"><div id="lefttop">left top</div></div>
     <div class="overlay"><div id="righttop">right top</div></div>
     <p></p>
     <div class="overlay"><div id="leftbottom">left bottom</div></div>
     <div class="overlay"><div id="rightbottom">right bottom</div></div>

 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {

    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
    z-index: -1;
}

p { clear: both; }

#main {

    float: left;
    margin: 50px;
    background: black;

}

#main div {

    position: relative;
    float: left;

    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;

}

.overlay {

    height: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;

}

#lefttop { background: yellow; }
#righttop { background: green; }
#leftbottom { background: red; }
#rightbottom { background: blue; }
```

**jQuery:**

```
var $divs = $("div", ".overlay"),
    optionsOver = {

         width: "300px",
         height: "300px"

    },
    optionsOut = {

         width: "150px",
         height: "150px"

    };

$divs.hover(function() {

    $divs
        .stop(true,true)
        .parent()
        .css({"z-index" : "1"});

    if (this.id == "lefttop") {

        optionsOver.left = "0px";
        optionsOver.top = "0px";

    } else if (this.id == "righttop") {

        optionsOver.left = "-=150px";
        optionsOver.top = "0px";

    } else if (this.id == "leftbottom") {

        optionsOver.left = "0px";
        optionsOver.top= "-=150px";

    } else if (this.id == "rightbottom") {

        optionsOver.left = "-=150px";
        optionsOver.top= "-=150px";

    }

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.stop(true,true);
    $this.parent().css({"z-index" : "99"});
    $this.animate(optionsOver, 400);

 }, function() {

    if (this.id == "lefttop") {

        optionsOut.left = "0px";
        optionsOut.top = "0px";

    } else if (this.id == "righttop") {

        optionsOut.left = "+=150px";
        optionsOut.top = "0px";

    } else if (this.id == "leftbottom") {

        optionsOut.left = "0px";
        optionsOut.top= "+=150px";

    } else if (this.id == "rightbottom") {

        optionsOut.left= "+=150px";
        optionsOut.top = "+=150px";

    }

    $(this)
        .stop(true,true)
        .animate(optionsOut, 400, function() {
            $divs.parent().css({"z-index" : "1"});
        });

 });
```

Comment: The main trick was to wrap each div in another div with class `.overlay`. That class was set to `height: 0` and `overflow: visible`.  Then when a div is moused over we set all `.overlay` divs to `z-index: 1` while setting the moused over `.overlay` div to `z-index: 99`. The combination of the `.overlay` css and the moused over action tells the browser not to push the other HTML elements around.

Comment: I also moved the object literals up top so that we don't have to retype a bunch of identical properties, as well as, adding `.stop(true,true)` to eliminate animation queuing.

Comment: That is excellent, thank you! I will adopt these optimizations immediately.

Comment: Don't forget, it's always nice to upvote (+1) all answers that help you =D

Comment: It says I don't have a high enough reputation for that, but I will as soon as I do. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jace - Yea, you need 15 rep for that. No worries.